# How can I set a tabindex attribute on a pie chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have a basic pie chart with 3 wedges. When you click on a wedge of the pie, a tooltip will display. My intent is to have the same functionality for a keydown event.

Scenario: When a pie slice has focus, a user can hit a key (ex: enter) which will display the tooltip exactly how the click event does.

I figured this will require 2 steps.

1. Make each pie wedge (.nv-slice) focusable by adding a 'tabindex = 0' attribute
2. Add an event listener that triggers the tooltip similar to how a click event does.

Here is the plunkr that shows the described behavior:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7WkFK2LqzDyDmnIt2xlf?p=preview
(thanks to  @ThanasisGrammatopoulos)

First things first, how can I add a tabindex attribute to each pie wedge? When I try the following code it does not seem to appear when I hit 'tab' to hit the ' .nv-slice ' element:

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice').attr("tabindex", "0");
```

Any ideas?